# Как сделать чтобы QPainter рисовал фигуры в том же окне, где находятся кнопка и поле ввода?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt, qt-designer, qpainter

Есть такой код, рисует прямоугольник рядом с кнопкой при нажатии:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor, QBrush
import sys

class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.flag = False

    def initUI(self):
        self.setFixedSize(400, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle('Colours')
        self.btn = QPushButton("Paint", self)
        self.btn.move(100, 100)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        self.show()

    def onClicked(self):
        self.flag = True
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        if self.flag:
            qp = QPainter()
            qp.begin(self)
            self.drawRectangles(qp)
            qp.end()

    def drawRectangles(self, qp):
        col = QColor(0, 0, 0)
        col.setNamedColor('#d4d4d4')
        qp.setPen(col)
        qp.setBrush(QColor(200, 0, 0))
        qp.drawRect(10, 15, 90, 60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

---

Через *Qt Designer* создал интерфейс и пытаюсь сделать так же, чтобы в этом же окне рисовать фигуры.

Как сделать чтобы QPainter рисовал фигуры в том же окне, где находятся кнопка и поле ввода?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor, QBrush
import sys


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        #self.flag = False
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(674, 473)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 110, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 110, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tabWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        #self.flag = False
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 1"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 2"))

    def onClicked(self):
        self.flag = True
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        if self.flag:
            qp = QPainter()
            qp.begin(self)
            self.drawRectangles(qp)
            qp.end()

    def drawRectangles(self, qp):
        col = QColor(0, 0, 0)
        col.setNamedColor('#d4d4d4')
        qp.setPen(col)
        qp.setBrush(QColor(200, 0, 0))
        qp.drawRect(10, 15, 90, 60)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ код, сгенерированный *Qt Designer*, НИКОГДА. 
   Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.
2. Вам надо встроить встроить виджет в форму, которую вы создаете в *Qt Designer*.\

   ...

   `self.tab = Tab_1Widget()`

   ...

   и в нем переопределить `paintEvent(self, event)`
3. > void QWidget::[**paintEvent**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#paintEvent)(QPaintEvent *event)
   >
   > Этот обработчик событий может быть повторно реализован в подклассе для получения событий рисования, передаваемых в `event`. 
   > ...

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor, QBrush


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(674, 473)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        
# ---    self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
# +++
        self.tab = Tab_1Widget()                                     # +++      
        
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 110, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 110, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tabWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

# ---      self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 1"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 2"))


# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
class Tab_1Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.flag = False

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        if self.flag:
            qp = QPainter()
            qp.begin(self)
            self.drawRectangles(qp)
            qp.end()

    def drawRectangles(self, qp):
        col = QColor(0, 0, 0)
        col.setNamedColor('#d4d4d4')
        qp.setPen(col)
        qp.setBrush(QColor(200, 0, 0))
        qp.drawRect(10, 15, 90, 60)        
        

# --------------------> vvvvvvvvvvv  vvvvvvvvvvvvv <----------------------
class Example(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)                                           # +++

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)              # +++

    def onClicked(self):
#        self.flag = True
        self.tab.flag = True                                         # +++
        
        self.update()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Example()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Здравствуйте! Можете объяснить как работают flag и update или скинуть где прочитать про них, не получается найти?

Comment: @User привет, `update()` - читаем https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#update . `flag` - это обычная переменная , которая принимает значение ИСТИНА или ЛОЖЬ